# Are two Seifert surfaces with the same Seifert matrix ambient isotopic?

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

Are two Seifert surfaces with the same Seifert matrix ambient isotopic? I assume not, but it would be really helpful to have a counter example.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let me suggest that you [add some context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) to your post. In this situation, good context might include the results of your own literature search, even if (especially if) it was all negative.

Comment: To be honest, I do not know where to start with this. I understand that $S$-equivalency is the optimal relation on th set of Seifert matrix, as any $A\mapsto PAP^T$ represents a basechange and any right-/ resp. left-enlargement can be realized by the addition of a tube to our surface / applying a surgery along an arc. Thus the question arises wether two Seifert surfaces with the same Seifert form are already isotopic. However I dont see how to go back from the surface beeing essentially linked in the same way with respect to a basis as the other surface to an isotopy between those two surfaces

Comment: Well, for example, entering the search term *Seifert matrix* into Wikipedia, the 5th link I got was [this paper of Levine](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/levineicm.pdf), in which the first theorem on page 96 seems to address your question somewhat.

Comment: Next, looking that paper up on MathSciNet, and then clicking on the MathSciNet button which lists later papers citing it, there's lots of information to explore.

Comment: I actually read through the linked paper by Levine already. However it only deals with the case of higher dimensional knots. See condition (2) in the theorem.

Comment: I will go through MathSciNet. Thank you for the reference. I am sorry if the question came across effortless. I have to admit I just looked up the two papers on S-equivalency I know. And as Lickorish wouldnt help me neither I just came here..

Comment: If I can not find anything I will add some context to the question tomorrow

Comment: No need to apologize. It's just that questions like this can be greatly improved by incorporating not just one's own "efforts", but also background from the literature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is too good to be true! Here are two Seifert surfaces for the unknot. They're both from taking a tubular neighborhood of a knot (the first, an unknot, the second, a figure-eight) then cutting out a disk.

[image: non-ambient-isotopic seifert surfaces]

They're certainly not ambient isotopic since the $\beta$ curve in the second one is a figure eight, which is not a torus knot. Furthermore, with respect to the $\alpha,\beta$ basis for each, the Seifert matrices for both are
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
At least, I think I got that right, using the $A_{ij}=\operatorname{lk}(x_i^{-},x_j)$ convention.

Comment: Thank you very much, as always your help is greatly appreciated! May I ask what you think about the assumption that any two Seifert surfaces for the same knot are isotopic after 1 stabilization, that is applying a surgery along an arc? Coming from the algebraic persepctive where $S$ equivalent matrices are already congruent after one enlargement?

Comment: @WhenYouHaveNoClue I think that's still too much to hope for -- I think you can make a counterexample by taking a genus-two surface rather than a torus and knotting up both of the handles.  Your observation still probably leads to something interesting though. I wonder if it's known whether any two genus-minimal Seifert surfaces are related by a single stabilization and destabilization? My examples are sort of trivial because they're neither genus-minimal nor incompressible.

Comment: I had the same exact question in mind! But couldn't find anything so far unfortunately.